# Endless loop when importing a variable from another file in Python

Tags: python, loops, import

I have a file called main.py and based on the user input I want to run the code either from file export.py, either from file import.py. This is how my code from main.py looks:

```
print("Hi, " + os.getlogin() + "!")
print("Extracting filenames...")
path = input('Tell me the path!\n')
filenames = [x for x in os.listdir(path)]
ID = [f for f in filenames if re.search("(?<=ID)(\d+)", f)]
filestxt = "Files.txt"
idtxt = "ID.txt"
PathFiles = os.path.join(path, filestxt)
PathID = os.path.join(path, idtxt)
file = open(PathFiles, "w+")
file.write('\n'.join(ID))
file.close()
with open(PathID, 'w') as f:
    for item in ID:
        list = re.findall("(?<=ID)(\d+)", item)
        string = ('\n'.join(list))
        f.write("%s\n" % string)


key = input("Export or Import(e/i)?:")
    if key == 'e':
        os.system('python export.py')
```

When I am hitting the 'e' button Python is running the code from export.py, but when it gets to the line

```
from main import PathID
```

instead of importing the variable which I need for the following function

```
    with open(PathID) as f:
        for line in f:
        ...
```

the code from main.py is running again and again from the beginning and I get the following lines in the console:

```
"Hi, " + os.getlogin() + "!"
"Extracting filenames..."
'Tell me the path!\n'
"Export or Import(e/i)?:"
```

All I want in export.py is to tell Python to read the ID.txt file from the path I have specified in the main.py file.

How can I call the function from main.py in export.py without getting this endless loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

before

```
key = input ("Export or Import (e / i) ?:")
     if key == 'e':
         os.system ('python export.py')
```

or before any code that should always be executed at startup.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Jossnix's answer:

When you execute `os.system('python export.py')`, you're launching a separate Python interpreter process.

When you execute `from main import PathID` within export.py, all of the code in main.py is run, and then, once it's finished running, the control flow is returned to export.py and it has access to `PathID`. The problem is that, as it stands, your main.py asks for user input. So, your main.py is stuck waiting for user input - you have to provide the input again to this new Python interpreter session! Hence, export.py is stuck while trying to import main.

Jossnix's solution works because it ensures that the user input component of main.py does not get run if main.py is being imported from another module, but will be run if main.py is executed as the main script.

I think you should get rid of the `os.system('python export.py')` line entirely. It's wasteful: you're launching a completely separate Python interpreter session and the print messages in main.py get run again (this is pretty confusing for the end-user!). I'd say you're better off having whatever code you want to run if the user enters the key 'e' wrapped in a function, and then run this function directly from main.py (if the user has indeed entered 'e'). You could do this: Create such a function (`f`) in export.py, taking a `PathID` argument. Then, within main.py, `from export import f`. Finally, if the user entered 'e', run `f(PathID, ...)`.